# How do I pass a variable through multiple subroutines in perl?

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine

I have a variable currentUser in a sub routine. It carries through to one subroutine, but does not carry through to another subroutine. How can I pass a variable through multiple subroutines while keeping the value?

```
sub login {
    &app_header;
    print <<EOF;
<form name="macform" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"       action="$fullurl">
    ...stuff
    EOF  
}

sub html_menu {
    $me = $currentUser;
    print $me;
    print <<EOF;
    <form name="menuform" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"     action="$fullurl">
    ..stuff
    EOF
    &app_list_button;
    print "<br>";
    &app_search_button;
    print "<br>";
    &app_edit_button;
    print "</div>";
}
```

When I attempt to do the same thing the html_form sub does with currentUser in a new sub called after html_form), the variable does not display as what the user entered during login.

Comment: This would be a better question if you would include a short code snippet showing what you are trying to do and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Show the html_form sub as well... you don't have to include anything not related to the variable.

Comment: I stand corrected. The code snippet and explanation are not making this a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub first {
    my $currentUser = shift;
    second($currentUser);
}

sub second {
    my $currentUser = shift;
    third($currentUser);
}
```

...and so on.

Passing a variable as argument is done through the `@_` variable. You should not attempt to use global variables, it is not a good way to do it. You can do it like so:

```
my ($arg1, $arg2, @rest) = @_;
```

Or by using `shift`, `pop` and the other methods of manipulating arrays, like I above used `shift`.

If you are not already doing so, I recommend very strongly that you use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

It will help you solve many simple problems.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the help! Pardon my perl stupidity.

Comment: @user1703986 You're welcome. You should only call subs with the `name($arg)` method, unless you explicitly are trying to achieve something different, which is described in perldoc perlsub.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is to use the variable as an argument:

```
sub r1 {
    my $arg = shift;
    r2($arg);
}

sub r2 {
    my $arg = shift;
    print "$arg in r2\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I attempt to do the same thing the html_form sub does with currentUser in a new sub called after html_form), the variable does not display as what the user entered during login.

Firstly, this is a rather complex example. You should have tried to break it down. To add to what others have said thus far, I'm going to tell you the `&` prefix on a subroutine's name without adding `()` changes the meaning. You use this in your examples, and I'm not sure if you know what it does. All of these have slightly different meanings.

- `foo()` This simply calls sub `foo` with no arguments.
- `&foo` This calls `foo` passing in `@_` implicitly. Important note, if `foo` modifies `@_` by reference then the `@_` will change for the callee too.
- `&foo()` This is just a relic of perl4. This calls `foo` with the explicit subref sigil. This is deprecated in all contexts.

*there are also minor differences with prototypes and the `&` sigil that are outside of the bounds of the question*

For more information see `perldoc -q "calling a function"` and `perldoc perlsub`